# How to selectively filter or block non-http/s traffic?

Tags: router, squid, traffic-filtering

I know that it is possible to filter **web content**, say, with Squid+ICAP Server.

But, is it conceptually as well as practically possible to monitor, filter, and programatically transform **arbitrary** (outgoing + incoming) traffic crossing your organization's routers?

For example, if a programmer in your organization decides to employ a client-server program purposely built to send sensitive data out of the organization (with his server listening on standard http/s port or any other known/arbitrary port somewhere on the Internet), then using what techniques and software can this malicious attempt be monitored and controlled?

I'm interested in getting some pointers on both the concepts/techniques involved, as well as some Linux-based FOSS suggestions that I could explore further. Note that, DLP products such as MyDLP talk only about web content, and not the above scenario, namely, of data theft via a purpose-built program using standard or non-standard data transfer protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Is it possible to monitor/filter/transform arbitrary traffic?

Yes. It's certainly conceptually possible. Before routers were readily available and cheap, it was common to find a cheap old computer, install Linux and share the network connection (IP Masquerading, etc.). You could watch everything just with `tcpdump`, if nothing else. And that is **everything** - you'll see every SYN-ACK handshake, every SSL certificate request, every DNS lookup, etc.

## What techniques could help monitor/control?

The obvious one is to watch for **what hosts you're connecting too**. Lots of tools to help with that, same stuff that keeps kids of adult sites and employees off facebook. See [this unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36714) question, notably [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/).

**Restricting ports** certainly reduces the space. A port is just an arbitrary number, but I've consulted for paranoid organizations that locked out everything except port 80. That forced us to do things like [tunnel ssh over https](http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/) or more elaborate schemes (two-headed ssh tunnels) when we needed to get stuff from back home.

But that still leaves a scary upload-company-secrets tunnel that just looks like HTTPS. I've been playing with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) a lot recently. If you were really hell-bent on catching everything, you'd **situate an https logging proxy in the middle**, and just declare that everyone inside your shop has to accept your certificate, which means you watch everything. So much for privacy, of course -- you'll see people gmail passwords in plain text (really! try it and see!) -- but it's gonna get awfully tricky for your black hat to get anything out without you noticing.

Useful thought experiment, anyway.

Comment: * "... watch for what hosts you're connecting to."* But how do I do that? Which tools?

Comment: Added note on ntop; also a suggestion - play with tcpdump, you'll get a great feel for what's actually going on.